# How do I use the fastai saved model?

Tags: pytorch, fast-ai

I trained my model in google colab, and downloaded the .pkl file in my computer. Now, how do I use it?  How do I load the .pkl file and do I need to install fastai for it to work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
from fastbook import load_learner

learn_inference = load_learner(filename)
```

See: https://docs.fast.ai/learner.html#load_learner
for the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I load the .pkl file

Assuming you've saved your model using [`learner.save`](https://docs.fast.ai/learner.html#Learner.save) you can use complementary [`learner.load`](https://docs.fast.ai/learner.html#Learner.load) method.

> do I need to install fastai for it to work

Yes, you need `fastai` if you saved it this way. You could also save PyTorch model itself contained inside `learner` via:

```
torch.save(learner.model, "/path/to/model.pt") # or save it's state_dict, better option
model = torch.load("/path/to/model.pt")
```

Either way you need those libraries as `pickle` stores the data but `class` definition and creation has to be provided code-wise.

Comment: It returns an error. 'fastai.vision.learner' has no attribute 'load'.  And I used ```learn.export```  to export the file in .pkl format. Now I cannot seem to use it.

Comment: @RomanRegmi `fastai` version? Is it the latest one?

Comment: I used the one in google colab. So, I am not sure. However I tried using the saved model in google colab itself. I still got an error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67783858/fastai-str-object-has-no-attribute-apply-tfms-error

Comment: Your dependencies are outdated by one major release. Just checked on `colab` and it's `1.0.61`, while the latest release is `2.3.1` (according to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/fastai/)). __Please update your dependecies, those are really really really outdated!__

Answer (score 1):

```
from fastai.text.all import * 
learner=load_learner("YOUR-MODEL-PATH")
```

If you are using the latest version of fastai, you can do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://forums.fast.ai/t/unable-to-load-saved-model/104319):

> learn.save is paired with learn.load and saves the model, and potentially optimizer. learn.export is paired with load_learner for deployment

so you can `learn.load` only what you saved with `learn.save` e.g. as savepoints during training (with an active instance of `Learner`). And when you use `learn.export` (for deployment / in production), you can create a new learner with `learn = load_learner`